# Mono for Android Full Version Error Compilation Google Maps Library

Tags: c#, google-maps, xamarin.android

Im try to run my application with the full version of Mono for Android, and it throws me this error: Error executing task GenerateJavaStubs:AndroidManifest.xml: error 1: Unable to find library 'com.google.android.maps'. And on another forum i read that cause of these problem its because you have to use Googles Api AVD, but im using it. How can i solve it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to download the Google Maps addon in the Android SDK Manager:

http://docs.xamarin.com/android/tutorials/Maps_and_Location#Google_APIs_Add-On